# Drupal 7 update breaks CiviCRM

Tags: error, upgrade, drupal-7

My site is currently running Drupal 7.82 and CiviCRM 5.45.1.

When I try to update Drupal to 7.87, I get an error (below) and after that, CiviCRM is gone from the site.

> Error: Call to undefined function civicrm_initialize() in
> civicrm_member_roles_menu()
>
> (line 17 of
> /var/www/vhosts/sweetwatercollaborative.org/httpdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/civicrm_member_roles/civicrm_member_roles.module).
>
> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Any help much appreciated.  Thanks -JC

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED.  Here's how...

• revert to saved version of website

• update "Webform CiviCRM Integration" module

• update all modules Civi uses... Chaos Tools, Views

• update drush version from 7.4.0 to 8.4.10. This allowed me to change the $DRUSH_PHP environment variable to use PHP 7.3, eliminating this warning I was getting "CiviCRM requires at least PHP 7.2. (Currently using PHP 7.1.33)"

• perform the Drupal update again, as per https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/update/updating-drupal-using-drush